# Quantum Mechanics reference book similar to Classical Electrodynamics by Jackson (without QFT)

Tags: quantum-mechanics, resource-recommendations, education

Are there any good reference books for QM?, similar to Gravitation by MTW, Classical Electrodynamics by Jackson or Modern Classical Physics by Thorne and Blandford, preferably up to introductory relativistic QM, I know the subject is really vast.

Comment: See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/12175/

Comment: Principles of Quantum Mechanics, R. Shankar

Comment: E.B. Manoukian - Quantum Theory. A wide spectrum.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Advanced Quantum Mechanics by  Sakurai is, to me, a bridge between the standard introductory texts and relativistic quantum mechanics. It's an old book, but you may find it useful.

Apologies, my tablet won't carry the link, it keeps downloading the (free!!) PDf, but an internet search should locate it easily.